# Make Cocoa Window Fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl, fullscreen

I'm currently in the process of adding a fullscreen view to my OpenGL window in OS X. I'm not using OS X's "fullscreen mode" because I don't like the idea of taking over the users screen.

I have my own custom window class derived from `NSWindow` and in that class, I've overwritten the `toggleFullscreen:` selector:

```
- (void)toggleFullScreen:(id)sender
{
    _fullscreen = !_fullscreen;
    if(_fullscreen) {
        NSRect screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
        [self setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
        [self setFrame:screenRect display:YES];
        [self setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
        [self setOpaque:YES];
        [self setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];
    } else {
        NSRect screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
        unsigned int width = (unsigned int)(screenRect.size.width/2.0f);
        unsigned int height = (unsigned int)(screenRect.size.height/2.0f);
        NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, screenRect.size.height-height, width, height);

        [self setStyleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask];
        [self setFrame:frame display:YES];
        [self setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel];
        [self setOpaque:YES];
        [self setHidesOnDeactivate:NO];
    }
}
```

This seems to work mostly correctly, toggling between a fullscreen window (per Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH210-SW6)) and a window at half the screens resolution.

The problem is that toggling between the two modes makes my window "lose focus". If I hit the keyboard shortcut I'm using right after I switch the mode, I get the OS X error "beep". I have to click in the window to "reactivate" it before I can use the toggle again.

I've tried adding a `[self makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];` to my function, but that doesn't fix the issue. All I need is a way to keep the window "focused" during the transition. Except for that issue, this method works perfectly and requires no changes to my `NSView`.

**Edit**

Not sure if its relevant, but I'm creating this window programmatically, not loading it from a Nib.

Comment: Borderless windows is not key by default so You need to override `-canBecomeKeyWindow`:

    -(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
    {
     return YES;
    }  Also I would suggest to use `-setFrame:display:animate:` instead `-setFrame:display` then You will get nice animation.

Comment: @JustinBoo: Adding `canBecomeKeyWindow` didn't seem to make a difference. As for the rendering, I'm using `CVDisplayLink` :-)

Comment: For the record, there is a good page with related information [here](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BorderlessWindow), but it doesn't seem to offer a good solution either. Someone said using a `NSWindowController` would solve the issue, but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

An even easier method, which appears to be the correct modern way (as of Lion)...

In my NSApplicationDelegate's init method (sorry I'm new so my terms are wrong), after creating the window...

`[window setCollectionBehavior:(NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary)];`

Then fire off a `toggleFullScreen`, say from your menu, with target = nil.

It will then create a new named desktop with the icon, slide your window to it and make it fullscreen. Just like Google Chrome or Safari when you make them fullscreen. I too am doing it without a nib or xib or whatever the kids call it these days.

[This page](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/11/the-lions-full-screen-mode/) talks about doing it the Interface Builder way.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html) is the official Apple docs on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I come into this problem myself and found out that calling this before the setStyleMask:

```
[window orderOut:nil];
```

And this after the setStyleMask fixed the lost focus problem for me:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```